# How to compile newest source and find merkleRoot hash value?

Tags: source-code

I am following youtube video for make own coin.

I did below 4 lines command for compile  newest bitcoin source.

./autogen.sh

./configure

make

sudo make install

And run ./mycoind file at src/

after this, debug folder does not generated debug.log file like video at [Home/.mycoin/] folder.

This is for modify assert(block.hashMerfleRoot == uint256 ..... value.

Why and how to fix?

Thanks.